# WiFi Network adapter not found Ubuntu 21.04 HP lap top

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek, 21.04

sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:6001124000-6001127fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 7a:a3:76:b8:cd:83
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.11.0-17-generic firmware=RNDIS device ip=xxx link=yes multicast=yes
```

dkms status
virtualbox, 6.1.18, 5.11.0-17-generic, x86_64: installed
cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

## Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system

network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
F.09

Comment: What's the question (I can read the subject line)? When did this problem first show up? What have you done to try and cure the problem yourself? Have you Googled it? Have you searched here on AU? Etc...

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of: `rfkill list all` and `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl`. This may reveal the reason for why the network controller is unclaimed 

Comment: I installe Ubuntu 20.04, now 21.04 and since then i just lost, wifi connection. Tried many things, none of them worked out...                                                                                                                              rfkill list all                                                                                                                                          
  0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl - dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted

Comment: Did the wireless card work in 20.04? **Edit your question** and show me `dkms status` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Also `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT model # of your HP laptop.

Comment: Edit my post... Am new with this, sorry